# Prestashop text list grid is not defined Uncaught ReferenceError: text_list_grid is not defined

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I got this JS error in my console
Uncaught ReferenceError: text_list_grid is not defined(…) IN list.grid.js
it blocks all my js code . All I did is just running default bootstrap theme and it blocked my top horizantale menu , Any one can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just desactivated the CStheme Script module 
Probleme Solved